# SharePoint configuration Wizard fails at step 9 - "Failed to add the service connection point for this farm"

Tags: administration, central-administration, configuration-wizard

I am facing an issue with SharePoint 2010 Products Configuration Wizard. I have installed `SP1` and then `June 2011 CU` but after installation when I tried to run the "`SharePoint 2010 Products Configuration Wizard`", it is failing with an error at the 9th step.

Looking at the log file I could see below details related to the error.

> Successfully created security token service application
>
> 08/06/2014 17:13:38  12  INF            Creating service connection point for this farm ...
>
> 08/06/2014 17:13:39  12  WRN            Failed to add the service connection point for this farm
>
> 08/06/2014 17:13:39  12  INF            Entering function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
>
> 08/06/2014 17:13:39  12  INF              Resource id to be retrieved is ServiceConnectionPointNotCreatedEventLog for language English (United States)
>
> 08/06/2014 17:13:39  12  INF              Resource retrieved id ServiceConnectionPointNotCreatedEventLog is Unable to create a Service Connection Point in the current Active Directory domain. Verify that the SharePoint container exists in the current domain and that you have rights to write to it.
>
> 08/06/2014 17:13:39  12  INF            Leaving function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
>
> 08/06/2014 17:13:39  12  WRN            Unable to create a Service Connection Point in the current Active Directory domain. Verify that the SharePoint container exists in the current domain and that you have rights to write to it.
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: The object LDAP://CN=Microsoft SharePoint Products,CN=System,DC=XXX,DC=com doesn't exist in the directory.
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPServiceConnectionPoint.Ensure(String serviceBindingInformation)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.UpgradeTask.Run()
>
> 08/06/2014 17:13:47  12  INF            Entering function TaskCommon.TraceToPsconfigLogAndUpgradeManagerLog
>
> 08/06/2014 17:13:47  12  INF              Spawing off the upgrade job
>
> 08/06/2014 17:13:47  12  INF            Leaving function TaskCommon.TraceToPsconfigLogAndUpgradeManagerLog
>
> 08/06/2014 17:13:47  12  INF            Trying to start the SPAdminV4 service

I have searched to find a resolution for this issues but all of them require me to go to AD admin. In my case making any change in the AD is not possible mainly because it is a production AD and the administrator are not tracking (and do not want to track)  SharePoint installations as of now.

Is there any way I can skip creating service connection point for this farm?

Answer (score 2):

I resolved the issue.

I used the command: `psconfig -cmd upgrade -inplace v2v -passphrase <passphrase> -wait`

Details available [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f152d071-c2f2-4374-b76e-b138a3547553/sharepoint-configuration-wizard-error-failed-to-add-the-service-connection-point-for-this-farm?forum=sharepointadminprevious)

Comment: Please include the details in your post, your answer is not very helpful the day that link breaks!

Comment: The link has no more information than what already posted here

Answer (score 2):

It may be necessary to grant permissions to the container in the AD,
please see [Track SharePoint 2010 Installations by Service Connection Point (AD Marker)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/opal/2010/04/18/track-sharepoint-2010-installations-by-service-connection-point-ad-marker/)

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue today on our test servers when installing the monthly CU my resolution was to open the SharePoint Admin PowerShell Console and ran the first command below on all the (APP & WFE) servers in the farm, then clicked the refresh button (I did not close the Config Wizard, but if you have, just run the command on servers and then re-open Config Wizard). I was able to continue running the Config Wizard on the APP Servers. On the WFE Servers however, Config Wizard still failed, so then I ran the second command below to force it to run in the SPAdmin PowerShell Console basically by-passing the need for the Config Wizard GUI and it finished with no errors:

First command (This command takes a long time to complete like 5-10 minutes for me, on all servers, but you can run in parallel since its looking locally):

```
Get-SpProduct –local
```

Then I clicked refresh button on the Config Wizard (or re-open config wizard if you closed it), as previously stated Config Wizard then worked for APP Servers (Next, Next, Next, blah, blah), but still failed on step 9 for the WFE Servers, such a bummer... So I decided to run this command from the SPAdmin PowerShell Console and it worked to finish out upgrading the farm with the latest CU's:

Second Command(s):

```
 CD "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\BIN\"
```

Press enter to change to the BIN

```
 PSCONFIG.EXE -cmd helpcollections -installall -cmd secureresources -cmd services -install -cmd installfeatures -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force -wait
```

Press enter again to start the Config Wizard inside the SPAdmin PowerShell Console essentially, it should run thru all the steps and finish normally

This second command is especially nice since I did not originally setup the farm and no one knows the passphrase used... I know what you are thinking... My thoughts too!...

Hope it helps.
SG.